zfs pool online but can't be imported "one or more devices is currently unavailable"
I recently moved my zfs pool from a 5 bay drive to a 10 bay drive and it can not be imported any more. The pool (nextcloud) appears to be online but when I tried to import it, it throws "one or more devices is currently unavailable" error. Tried both -m and -f flag.
root@truenas:~# zpool import
   pool: backpool
     id: 5882512777125610777
  state: ONLINE
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
 config:

    backpool                                  ONLINE
      raidz2-0                                ONLINE
        0739257a-7070-44c6-b402-584dff293934  ONLINE
        048ccec6-609c-4879-b2a6-59f91e8aa71b  ONLINE
        f99db7ee-c100-44b0-93eb-b16bbda6bf51  ONLINE
        feb29f48-e7c2-40ea-9592-c9c84453d443  ONLINE
root@truenas[~]# zpool import -m backpool
cannot import 'backpool': one or more devices is currently unavailable

root@truenas[~]# zpool import -f backpool
cannot import 'backpool': one or more devices is currently unavailable

zpool event -v -f
Apr  7 2024 13:14:09.308369906 ereport.fs.zfs.probe_failure
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.probe_failure"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0x471942a8b28f4e49
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0x471942a8b28f4e49
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/048ccec6-609c-4879-b2a6-59f91e8aa71b"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x4955621b1f98
        vdev_delta_ts = 0xb25bca0
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x0
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        prev_state = 0x0
        time = 0x6612fe91 0x126159f2
        eid = 0x2df

Apr  7 2024 13:14:09.308369906 resource.fs.zfs.statechange
        version = 0x0
        class = "resource.fs.zfs.statechange"
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        vdev_guid = 0x471942a8b28f4e49
        vdev_state = "FAULTED" (0x5)
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/048ccec6-609c-4879-b2a6-59f91e8aa71b"
        vdev_laststate = "ONLINE" (0x7)
        time = 0x6612fe91 0x126159f2
        eid = 0x2e0

Apr  7 2024 13:14:09.676372303 ereport.fs.zfs.probe_failure
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.probe_failure"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0xb8b127f0df8c690d
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0xb8b127f0df8c690d
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/f99db7ee-c100-44b0-93eb-b16bbda6bf51"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x495577f9c770
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x2104302a
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x0
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        prev_state = 0x0
        time = 0x6612fe91 0x28509f4f
        eid = 0x2e1

Apr  7 2024 13:14:09.676372303 resource.fs.zfs.statechange
        version = 0x0
        class = "resource.fs.zfs.statechange"
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        vdev_guid = 0xb8b127f0df8c690d
        vdev_state = "FAULTED" (0x5)
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/f99db7ee-c100-44b0-93eb-b16bbda6bf51"
        vdev_laststate = "ONLINE" (0x7)
        time = 0x6612fe91 0x28509f4f
        eid = 0x2e2

Apr  7 2024 13:16:34.761317150 ereport.fs.zfs.delay
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.delay"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/feb29f48-e7c2-40ea-9592-c9c84453d443"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x49773fb9e91f
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x21e8c40d20
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x1
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        zio_err = 0x5
        zio_flags = 0xb00c1
        zio_stage = 0x2000000
        zio_pipeline = 0x2100000
        zio_delay = 0x21e8c40b7b
        zio_timestamp = 0x495556f5dbff
        zio_delta = 0x21e8c40d20
        zio_priority = 0x1
        zio_offset = 0xae9ffcc2000
        zio_size = 0x2000
        time = 0x6612ff22 0x2d60c71e
        eid = 0x2e3

Apr  7 2024 13:16:34.765317176 ereport.fs.zfs.delay
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.delay"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/feb29f48-e7c2-40ea-9592-c9c84453d443"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x49773fec23ed
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x21e8f66847
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x2
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        zio_err = 0x5
        zio_flags = 0xb00c1
        zio_stage = 0x2000000
        zio_pipeline = 0x2100000
        zio_delay = 0x21e8f66639
        zio_timestamp = 0x495556f5bba6
        zio_delta = 0x21e8f66847
        zio_priority = 0x1
        zio_offset = 0xae9ffc82000
        zio_size = 0x2000
        time = 0x6612ff22 0x2d9dd038
        eid = 0x2e4

Apr  7 2024 13:16:34.769317202 ereport.fs.zfs.delay
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.delay"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/feb29f48-e7c2-40ea-9592-c9c84453d443"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x4977401c7fca
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x21e9278754
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x3
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        zio_err = 0x5
        zio_flags = 0xb00c1
        zio_stage = 0x2000000
        zio_pipeline = 0x2100000
        zio_delay = 0x21e9278438
        zio_timestamp = 0x495556f4f876
        zio_delta = 0x21e9278754
        zio_priority = 0x1
        zio_offset = 0x42000
        zio_size = 0x2000
        time = 0x6612ff22 0x2ddad952
        eid = 0x2e5

Apr  7 2024 13:16:34.769317202 ereport.fs.zfs.probe_failure
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.probe_failure"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/feb29f48-e7c2-40ea-9592-c9c84453d443"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x4977401c7fca
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x21e9278754
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x3
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        prev_state = 0x0
        time = 0x6612ff22 0x2ddad952
        eid = 0x2e6

Apr  7 2024 13:16:34.769317202 resource.fs.zfs.statechange
        version = 0x0
        class = "resource.fs.zfs.statechange"
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        vdev_guid = 0xc23d1fe5ce69a038
        vdev_state = "FAULTED" (0x5)
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/feb29f48-e7c2-40ea-9592-c9c84453d443"
        vdev_laststate = "ONLINE" (0x7)
        time = 0x6612ff22 0x2ddad952
        eid = 0x2e7

Apr  7 2024 13:16:35.113319443 ereport.fs.zfs.delay
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.delay"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/0739257a-7070-44c6-b402-584dff293934"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x497754c5a664
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x21fdd30f44
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x1
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        zio_err = 0x5
        zio_flags = 0xb00c1
        zio_stage = 0x2000000
        zio_pipeline = 0x2100000
        zio_delay = 0x21fdd30d74
        zio_timestamp = 0x495556f29720
        zio_delta = 0x21fdd30f44
        zio_priority = 0x1
        zio_offset = 0x42000
        zio_size = 0x2000
        time = 0x6612ff23 0x6c11e13
        eid = 0x2e8

Apr  7 2024 13:16:35.117319469 ereport.fs.zfs.delay
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.delay"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/0739257a-7070-44c6-b402-584dff293934"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x497755015cca
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x21fe0a0405
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x2
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        zio_err = 0x5
        zio_flags = 0xb00c1
        zio_stage = 0x2000000
        zio_pipeline = 0x2100000
        zio_delay = 0x21fe0a0184
        zio_timestamp = 0x495556f758c5
        zio_delta = 0x21fe0a0405
        zio_priority = 0x1
        zio_offset = 0xae9ffcc2000
        zio_size = 0x2000
        time = 0x6612ff23 0x6fe272d
        eid = 0x2e9

Apr  7 2024 13:16:35.121319495 ereport.fs.zfs.delay
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.delay"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/0739257a-7070-44c6-b402-584dff293934"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x49775539a300
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x21fe437788
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x3
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        zio_err = 0x5
        zio_flags = 0xb00c1
        zio_stage = 0x2000000
        zio_pipeline = 0x2100000
        zio_delay = 0x21fe4375dc
        zio_timestamp = 0x495556f62b78
        zio_delta = 0x21fe437788
        zio_priority = 0x1
        zio_offset = 0xae9ffc82000
        zio_size = 0x2000
        time = 0x6612ff23 0x73b3047
        eid = 0x2ea

Apr  7 2024 13:16:35.121319495 ereport.fs.zfs.probe_failure
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.probe_failure"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/0739257a-7070-44c6-b402-584dff293934"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x49775539a300
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x21fe437788
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x3
        parent_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        prev_state = 0x0
        time = 0x6612ff23 0x73b3047
        eid = 0x2eb

Apr  7 2024 13:16:35.121319495 resource.fs.zfs.statechange
        version = 0x0
        class = "resource.fs.zfs.statechange"
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        vdev_guid = 0x2d10c27c3b3c204d
        vdev_state = "FAULTED" (0x5)
        vdev_path = "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/0739257a-7070-44c6-b402-584dff293934"
        vdev_laststate = "ONLINE" (0x7)
        time = 0x6612ff23 0x73b3047
        eid = 0x2ec

Apr  7 2024 13:16:35.121319495 ereport.fs.zfs.vdev.no_replicas
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.vdev.no_replicas"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        vdev_type = "raidz"
        vdev_ashift = 0xc
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x0
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x0
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x0
        parent_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        parent_type = "root"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        prev_state = 0x1
        time = 0x6612ff23 0x73b3047
        eid = 0x2ed

Apr  7 2024 13:16:35.121319495 ereport.fs.zfs.zpool
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.zpool"
        ena = 0x955621b406e00001
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        time = 0x6612ff23 0x73b3047
        eid = 0x2ee

Apr  7 2024 13:16:36.157326242 ereport.fs.zfs.vdev.no_replicas
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.vdev.no_replicas"
        ena = 0x97792f6fd0a00401
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
                vdev = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0xdb9e5218f33810dd
        vdev_type = "raidz"
        vdev_ashift = 0xc
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x0
        vdev_delta_ts = 0x0
        vdev_read_errors = 0x0
        vdev_write_errors = 0x0
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x0
        parent_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        parent_type = "root"
        vdev_spare_paths =
        vdev_spare_guids =
        prev_state = 0x1
        time = 0x6612ff24 0x9609ba2
        eid = 0x2ef

Apr  7 2024 13:16:36.157326242 ereport.fs.zfs.zpool
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.zpool"
        ena = 0x97792f6fd0a00401
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        (end detector)
        pool = "backpool"
        pool_guid = 0x51a2e2343344c519
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x2
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        time = 0x6612ff24 0x9609ba2
        eid = 0x2f0



Please post the output of zpool events -v -f nextcloud when trying to import your pool.

@shodanshok updated. I was able to "fix" nextcloud pool by pulling out a faulty drive, now backpool got the same issue..

Some devices appear as FAULTED, so you probably have an hardware issues. You can check SMART and dmesg to get more info.
